# How do I exclude certain form fields upon submission of the form without disabling the field

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

If I have a form with the following 3 fields:

First Name Last Name Date Of Birth

When the user fills in all 3 fields and submits you will get the URL

```
http: //fakeURL.php?firstName=Fred&lastName=Flintstone&DateOfBirth=2/5/1952
```

However, if the user only fills in First Name and Date Of Birth you will get

```
http: //fakeURL.php?firstName=Fred&lastName=&DateOfBirth=2/5/1952 (where lastName has no value)
```

How do I achieve

```
http: //fakeURL.php?firstName=Fred&DateOfBirth=2/5/1952 (where lastName and value are removed from the URL)
```

I don't want to disable the input field upon using onsubmit. Is there a better way than disabled the input field?

Please help...

Comment: *Why* don't you want to disable the field in a "submit" handler?

Comment: why does it matter that the field is empty?  In any case, have you considered using POST rather than GET so that your URLs are cleaner and more of your implementation is hidden from visitors.

Answer (score 25):

Just remove the "name" attribute from the input element.

```
// using jQuery
$('#inputId').removeAttr('name');

// native Javascript
document.getElementById('inputId').removeAttribute('name');
```

Comment: This is much simpler than the top answer and works very well for the case when some input exists only to help the user in some way and need not be submitted (in which case we simply don't give it a `name` in the first place).

Comment: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jqpw7eef/) (use the network panel of the developer console to examine the sent request, which should simply be `?sent=foo`).

Comment: Some types of inputs (e.g. `radio`) don't work properly without the `name` attribute.

Answer (score 5):

You must either:

1. Remove or disable the field from the form before submitting it
2. Don't submit the form, instead redirect to a URL you construct from the form yourself
3. Make an AJAX request instead of leaving the page

Aside from those options, you can't submit this form via GET without all the inputs becoming part of the URL. That's part of the HTML and HTTP specifications.

Answer (score 0):

if you are working on angular and using (ngModel), Remove the name attribute in the input field and add

[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"

Answer (score -1):

You should use forms with the `GET` method **only** when the new page is supposed to be bookmarked and passed around.

Since you are talking about you **taking input from the user** (and I presume you also store that input in a database or some similar permanent storage), you should be using `POST` **instead**.

Comment: Tell that to WordPress.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with *taking input from the user* and sending it with a `get` method. Having the input saved in the address bar benefits the user if they were to refresh the page, too.