# Exclude File <input type='file'> on form submission

Tags: asp.net, html, forms, post, action

I have a webform application.

There is a form has a set of textbox and one uploader, one **'Upload button'** and one 'Submit button'.

When a user select a file using the uploader (type='file') without click 'Upload' or forget to,
then he submits the form.

The server side will somehow read the file to somewhere.

I don't want the submit to include the selected file.

Apart from adding 'clean the uploader' in the submit function, what else can I do to let the form exclude the input(type=file) control?

Thx

tags [html][form][action][post]

Comment: You question is a bit unclear. Are you saying that you have an `input type="file"` on your form and that if a user selects a file, you **don't** want to upload it?

Comment: if you don't want them to upload a file, then don't put a file uploader on the page

Comment: @JamesHill    e.g. the use select a file but forget to click 'Upload'. he clicked the Submit instead.

Comment: @DanAn, It sounds like you have a UI problem.

Comment: Just remove "name" attribute from the input element. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869987/how-do-i-exclude-certain-form-fields-upon-submission-of-the-form-without-disabli/20877611#20877611)

Comment: Just remove "name" attribute from the input element. Here's [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869987/how-do-i-exclude-certain-form-fields-upon-submission-of-the-form-without-disabli/20877611#20877611)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer Myself

The submit button in the form will submit the file.

Regardless the server side code.

Sometimes user may forget to 'Upload the file' or go to another option, while the uploader is active and holds file.

In this case, we should clean or say 'remove' the file in the uploader.

The only solution is to use JavaScript (Let me know if I'm wrong).

Consider the speciality of html uploader, you can not control the 'Value' or 'Text'

Instead, I found the following two ways:

http://gusiev.com/2009/04/clear-upload-file-input-field/

http://aspnetupload.com/Clear-HTML-File-Input.aspx

Tested both work nicely.

Answer (score 2):

You can `disable` input, and it will not get submitted to server.

Also, you can make sure that [form does not have enctype="multipart/form-data"](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2) set.

Comment: The only problem here is that if you disable the input, you can't click the label or input to set the file in the first place. You could disable it after the upload though.

Answer (score 1):

When using an `input type="file"` on a form, you must also include `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form tag so that the file is processed. If you don't want the file to be send to the server, simply remove `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.