# Exclude div from form submitting by jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, submit

When I submit a form by jQuery, like this: `jQuery('#myForm').submit()`;
I don't want send some information in a specified div inside that form (I mean all input fields, select elements, textarea elements, etc are not allowed to sent to server), but I don't know to to prevent that div from submitting along with the owner form.
Could you please help me on this? Thank you so much.

---

Thank you all for your quickly replies. I tried to set "disabled" attribute to all input fields in that div to false, but when I checked it again on server, some other fields (such as select, textarea) were still submitted. I think I should disable them too. Is there any way to remove or "hidden/disable" the whole div without disabling each kind of input elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like this should do it:

```
$('div#excludeMyInputs input').prop("disabled",true);
$('#myform').submit();
$('div#excludeMyInputs input').prop("disabled",false);
```

Comment: This works except it does not handle `textarea` or `select` elements that might be in the form as well.

Comment: @ChristopherKing just need to do it ... `$('div#excludeMyInputs textarea')`

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you're probably going about it incorrectly if you have a form with inputs and you don't want to send the values of those inputs somewhere.

However, you could just put those form elements **outside** of your `#myForm` form element (for example, in a second form called `#myForm2`) and then these inputs would be ignored by the `jQuery('#myForm').submit();` but they would still be presented on the page.

Answer (score 1):

This previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869987/how-do-i-exclude-certain-form-fields-upon-submission-of-the-form-without-disabli) may assist you.  It looks like your best option will be to either disable or remove the form elements in the div before calling .submit()

Answer (score 1):

you could use the $.ajax function to choose what data to send:

```
$(document).on('submit','#myForm',function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url:$(this).attr('action'),
    type:'post',
    data:{
      input1:$('#input1').val(),
      input2:$('#input2').val()
      // etc etc
    },
    success:function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    },
    error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log(errorThrown);
    }
  });
});
```