# How to use custom DateRangePicker widget with Django Filter's DateFromToRangeFilter

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-filter

So I have this filter using `Django Filter`:

```
class AssignmentFilter(FilterSet):
    assignment_date = filters.DateFromToRangeFilter()
```

This built in class of Django Filter generates a form with these two inputs:

```
<input type="text" name="assignment_date_after" id="id_assignment_date_0">
<input type="text" name="assignment_date_before" id="id_assignment_date_1">
```

So there you pick the two dates and based on that it will get you the filtered QuerySet. All working well.

However I would like to use this usefull DateRangePicker:
https://www.daterangepicker.com/

This gets activated like this:

```
<input type="text" name="dates" class="form-control">

<script>
$('input[name="dates"]').daterangepicker();
</script>
```

However as you can see, this is only one field where the range between the dates will be set. But `Django Filter` works with an start input field and end input field.

How can I modify this so that I can use the nice widget that belongs to `input[name="dates"]`.

Maybe a solution is to process it with JavaScript after a `GET` request. The function will then take the start date and inject it into the `id_assignment_date_0` field. And take the end date and inject it to the `id_assignment_date_1` field. Both the field `id_assignment_date_0` and `id_assignment_date_1` will be visually hidden then in the form. It seems quite hacky though.

Does anyone have a clever solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this example](https://www.daterangepicker.com/#example1), you can accomplish what you want like this:

```
<input type="text" id="datePicker" name="dates" class="form-control">
<input type="hidden" name="assignment_date_after" id="id_assignment_date_0">
<input type="hidden" name="assignment_date_before" id="id_assignment_date_1">

<script>
$(function() {
  $('input[name="dates"]').daterangepicker({
    opens: 'left'
  }, function(start, end, label) {
    $('#id_assignment_date_0').val(start)
    $('#id_assignment_date_1').val(end)
  });
  $('#datePicker').removeAttr('name');
});
</script>
```

Although, the format might differ from what you need. You can also change the format with something like below:

```
$('#id_assignment_date_0').val(start.format('YYYY-MM-DD'))
```

Comment: This does not work. The parameters get very weird. Based on your anwser I get this url ending: `domain.com/somepage?dates=02%2F18%2F2020+-+02%2F20%2F2020&assignment_date_after=18%2F02%2F2020&assignment_date_before=18%2F02%2F2020`

Comment: The url I need to make the filter work: `domain.com/somepage?assignment_date_after=18%2F02%2F2020&assignment_date_before=20%2F02%2F2020`

Comment: I have edited the answer to disable sending `dates` parameter in your `GET` request.

Comment: You can just ignore the `dates` parameter in your backend and just use the parameters that you want.

Comment: When I use disabled I can not select any dates. The datepicker won't open then

Comment: Yes, that's not proper. Why not just ignore the `dates` parameter in your backend?

Comment: You can also use this *hack* mentioned in this thread. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43638170/3037529

Comment: Even if I ignore those parameters it still wouldn't work. Because look at my first comment. I used date range: `18-02-2020 - 20-02-2020` but for the `#id_assignment_date_0` and `#id_assignment_date_1` they both end up as 18-02-2020 as parameter. So it does not work

Comment: That's weird! Can you `console.log` both `start` and `end`? Do they look fine when you print them?

Comment: It's working now! I updated your answer. It was 99% correct, just add this line: `$('#datePicker').removeAttr('name');`  found it in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20877611/10938976

Comment: I'm using your code as have the same goal. But I'm getting both fields : the one from django-filter form and the second one rendered by JS. How to remove/hide django-filter field but still make it able to trace and filter parameters passed from JS rendered input?